# Como imprimir struct de strings em c?

Tags: c

Quando tempo imprimir strings de uma struct o programa até compila e retorna 0 mas os valores das strings não são os esperados. Segue o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct DATA{
 char nome[4];
 char sobrenome[6];
 char apelido[5];
 };

int main(){
 struct DATA cp;

 cp.nome[4] = "joao";
 cp.sobrenome[6] = "zuadao";
 cp.apelido[5] = "furao";

printf("%s / %s / %s\n", cp.nome, cp.sobrenome, cp.apelido);

return 0;
}
```

O valor retornado no console é: ↓@ / D / IÇ

Alguém pode me ajudar? obrigado.

Comment: O problema é que vc não está deixando espaço no vetor pro caractere vazio `'\0'`. Se vc copiar somente os 3 primeiros caracteres para nome `strcpy(cp.nome, "joa")` ou adicionar mais um espaço em nome `char nome[5]`, seu programa deve funcionar corretamente.

Comment: @aviana. Obrigado pela ajuda. Fiz o que vc falou. Mas o retorno continua não sendo os valores das strings. Esse problema só  acontece com struct.

Comment: int main()
{
    struct DATA cp;

    strcpy(cp.nome, "joa");
    strcpy(cp.sobrenome, "zuada");
    strcpy(cp.apelido, "fura");

    printf("%s / %s / %s\n", cp.nome, cp.sobrenome, cp.apelido);

    return 0;
}

Comment: Estou compilando o código que colei acima e está funcionando.

Comment: @aviana Muito obrigado! Salvou minha vida. Agora consegui construir o código que preciso pra universidade. vlw msm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sugiro que você não defina quantos carácteres a string tenha, pois quando você não consegue atribuir a string desse jeito, só por strcpy, aleḿ de você não estar deixando espaço para o caractere vazio '\0', e a vantagem da string é exatamente não precisar deixar um tamanho fixo, olha como eu deixei:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <string.h>

  struct DATA {
    char *nome;
    char *sobrenome;
    char *apelido;
  };

  int main()
  {
    struct DATA cp;

    cp.nome = "joaao";
    cp.sobrenome = "zuadao";
    cp.apelido = "furao";

    printf("%s / %s / %s\n", cp.nome, cp.sobrenome, cp.apelido);

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por compartilhar sua solução. Me ajudou a aprender bastante! ^^